# Checkboxes are getting but not putting many-to-many roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, roles, cancan, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set up a Rails 3 app to handle user roles with Devise and CanCan.

My relationships are as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users_roles
    has_many :roles, :through => :users_roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :users_roles
end

class UsersRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Actually everything is working fine. Devise is handling the authentication perfectly. CanCan is restricting user behaviour based on ability.rb.

But I have a ridiculous problem with setting a UsersRole.

I have defined checkboxes on the User edit page like so.

```
<% for role in Role.all %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
    <%=h role.name.camelize %>
<% end %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "user[role_ids][]", "" %>
```

If I create a UserRole via the console, then these checkboxes are checked according to the users role.

But I cannot set or change roles using these checkboxes!

I've been all around the houses with this — variations of syntax, switched to a HABTM and roles_mask approach, rebuilt my models and controllers several times — all to no effect.

Actually the title of my question is not entirely correct - the checkboxes are putting

```
_method put
authenticity_token  XGl6s1iyXJfahdgftc3df8q1ZeehMVzs3LxiQH98jGw=
commit  Update
user[current_password]  password
user[email] user@example.com
user[name]  User Name
user[password]  
user[password_confirmatio...    
user[role_ids][]    1
user[role_ids][]    4
user[role_ids][]    
utf8    ✓
```

But these values are not being set in the database.

What am I doing wrong??!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have specified attr_accesible in your User model and that role_ids is not listed there (and it should not be)

If that is combined with an update_attributes call in your Controller then role_ids will never be set properly.

If this is the case then you should manually be able to set the role_ids in your Controller like this before you update or save:

```
@user.role_ids = params[:user][:role_ids]
```

Of course, I'm not certain this is the case since you did not include your controller code or any details with the User model.

Edit:

Instead if doing the @user.update_attributes in the Controller, you could change it to the following instead:

```
 #The same as update_attributes, but without the save
@user.attributes = params[:user]

# Here the role_ids get assigned manually so it does not need to be in attr_accesible
@user.role_ids = params[:user][:role_ids] if params[:user]

# And here it gets checked if the save was successfull
if @user.save
  render :action => :show
else
  render :action => :edit
end
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct! It's always the little things that you overlook. I've specified role_ids as attr_accesible and all works. Now trying to implement your Controller. Would you call it as a before_save?

Comment: Great. Made some suggestions of how to handle it in the controller

Comment: I have the same exact code but view is not rendering and got a message : undefined method `first' for false:FalseClass.  please let me know what might be the problem